# IOS NSCharacterSet for emoji and latin characters

Tags: ios, emoji, nscharacterset

I'm trying to limit text user input to latin/english characters and emojis.

Is it possible to create an NSCharacterSet that includes all of these characters?

I tried using a keyboard type ASCIICapable on my input views, but then I don't get emoji input.

Comment: For anyone coming to this in the future, I needed this and made [an open source project called NSCharacterSet+EmojiCharacterSet](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/NSCharacterSet-EmojiCharacterSet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing built in to create such a specific character set. You'll have to do it yourself by character range.

The Emoji characters are essentially in the range \U1F300 - \U1F6FF. I suppose a few others are scattered about.

Use an `NSMutableCharacterSet` to build up what you need.

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *aCharacterSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
[aCharacterSet addCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0x1F300, 0x1F700 - 0x1F300)]; // Add most of the Emoji characters
[aCharacterSet addCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange('A', 'Z'-'A'+1)]; // Add uppercase
[aCharacterSet addCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange('a', 'z'-'a'+1)]; // Add lowercase
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, this is what I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Swift equivalent of **rmaddy**'s answer to add up ranges in a `CharacterSet`:

```
var aCharacterSet = CharacterSet()
aCharacterSet.insert(charactersIn: "\u{1F300}"..<"\u{1F700}") // Add most of the Emoji characters
aCharacterSet.insert(charactersIn: "A"..."Z") // Add uppercase
aCharacterSet.insert(charactersIn: "a"..."z") // Add lowercase
```

Also, you will find the complete list of Unicode ranges for emoji on http://www.unicode.org/charts/ under *Emoji & Pictographs*.